# Why is my mongo command no longer working in Bash?

Tags: mongodb

So mongo was running fine, and then I tried to create a database and a collection. Long story short, the server stopped responding. I thought (after about 6 hours of trying everything else, asking my friends and getting literally nowhere) that maybe I should just uninstall and reinstall mongoDB. Turns out that was a mistake, because now when I try to do the mongo command I get this

```
    $ mongo
bash: /c/Program Files/MongoDB/Server4.4/bin/mongo.exe: No such file or directory
```

I noticed that there is no `"/"` between `Server` and `4.4` --- I think that's the issue, but I have no idea how to fix that. An yes, I have added MongoDB to my system variable path...

What is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like commands are working now. I guess I just needed to wait like 8 hours!?